# Remove or hide the vertical scrollbar in GridView WinForms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, gridview, scrollbar

I have an application on WinForms for POS client. My client have a touch screen system so i need to implement buttons to scroll in GridView.

Now i am facing the problem is that i am unable to hide the scrollbar. When i tried to hide scroll bar a black splitted image appear

```
If TypeOf (sender) Is VScrollBar Then
                Dim scrollBar As VScrollBar = CType(sender, VScrollBar)
                If TypeOf (scrollBar.Parent) Is KryptonExtendedGrid Then
                    Dim KryptonGrid As KryptonExtendedGrid = CType(scrollBar.Parent, KryptonExtendedGrid)
                    If KryptonGrid.ScrollControl IsNot Nothing Then
                        If scrollBar.Visible Then
                            grdForecast.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None
                            scrollBar.Visible = False
                            scrollBar.Hide()
                            KryptonGrid.ScrollControl.DownButton.Enabled = True
                        Else
                            KryptonGrid.ScrollControl.DownButton.Enabled = False
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Usually, DataGrids have an option, in the designer, to show one/both or hide the ScrollBars. Does your grid have this option? There's a chance that hiding custom scrollbars at runtime may require to recreate the handle or otherwise *refresh* the grid.

Comment: The buttons, the lift and the bar are all integral parts of the scrollbar. If you want only buttons you need to add and code them separately. - also: What is WinFrom? and: Are you talking about DataGridViews or some other control like GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for you kind support. I have fix it by myself. I am sharing the code in case any one need help

```
Private Sub VScrollBar1_VisibleChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Try
            If TypeOf (sender) Is VScrollBar Then
                Dim scrollBar As VScrollBar = CType(sender, VScrollBar)
                If TypeOf (scrollBar.Parent) Is KryptonExtendedGrid Then
                    Dim KryptonGrid As KryptonExtendedGrid = CType(scrollBar.Parent, KryptonExtendedGrid)
                    If KryptonGrid.ScrollControl IsNot Nothing Then
                        If KryptonGrid.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical  Then
                            KryptonGrid.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None
                            KryptonGrid.ScrollControl.DownButton.Enabled = True
                        Else
                            KryptonGrid.ScrollControl.DownButton.Enabled = False
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

vb.net, tested, panel2 inside panel1, panel2's width a bit bigger than panel1 enough to hide the scrollbar:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

  Panel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible = False
  Panel1.VerticalScroll.Visible = False

  Panel2.AutoScroll = True
  Panel2.HorizontalScroll.Visible = False
  Panel2.VerticalScroll.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub Panel2_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel2.MouseWheel
  If Panel2.Bounds.Contains(e.Location) Then
    Dim vScrollPosition As Integer = Panel2.VerticalScroll.Value
    vScrollPosition = e.Location.Y
    Panel2.Invalidate()
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Panel2_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel2.MouseEnter
   Panel2.Select()
End Sub

End Class
```

this worked with 2 panels it will definitely work with anything in a panel inside another like a datagridview all you have to do is make the width bigger enough to hide the bar

this is an easy way because if you want to really hide them you're going to need to override the original control

Comment: Dear @devcon I have mention it i am using the gridview. your code for panel

Comment: Thats not works ... :( any how thanks for you response , i have also posted the answer